# jpa save entities in order, but query error

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, transactions

In my SpringBoot project, I save three entities A, B, C in order in a loop.like:

```
for (i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
    AService.save(Ai);
    BService.save(Bi);
    CService.save(Ci);
}
```

And in AService,BService,Cservice, they call ARepository's save method directly, which belongs to crudRepository. I add @Transactional annotation on ARepository:

```
public class AService {
    public save(A a) {
        ARepository.save(A);
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface ARepository {}
```

Logically, I save A, B, C in order, shouldn't they save in database in order ?
The problem is that I have another timed task which would join table A,B,C to query the data. And I found that sometime B exists but A not found... It occurs rarely but cause big problems. Why?
And I use Jpa + Posgresql.

Answer (score 0):

The whole loop should be wrapped in a `@Transactional` method. If you start a new transaction for every object, your database is going to have a hard time writing to the disk.

Comment: But shouldn't finish writing to the disk and the transaction finish then the method return? u mean that my code commit the transaction and return but the database have not write into the disk?

Comment: I mean that every transaction commit has to guarantee that the data is written to disk before control is returned to your code, so the database can not bundle up multiple changes this way. If you combine a few inserts in a transaction you will see better performance because the granularity in which a database writes to disk is based on the page size.